# Estimating how long for air inside spacecraft to escape from a hole

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum, flow, estimation

I'd like to know how long it would take for the air in a spacecraft to escape. I imagine this will be an iterative calculation, since as the air escapes into the vacuum of space the air pressure inside the craft decreases, but I need help with what formula to use (maybe in Excel). The variables would be the size of the hole, the internal volume of the spacecraft, and I would assume STP as the initial conditions.
Also it would be super to know the air speed as it exits the craft, at what point the remaining air becomes unbreathable for humans, and also what happens to the air inside the craft and time frames (temperature change, water condensation, etc.).

Comment: This seems to be a bit of a shopping list. Which bits of physics do you need to understand? Yu could do worse than look at the physics of water rockets - pretty much the same but without the propellant.

Comment: Just hoping for some equations that I can use to get an estimate, probably using excel. Hoping that someone can help with the other questions along the way!

Comment: @Susan I googled this: https://www.tlv.com/global/US/calculator/air-flow-rate-through-orifice.html There are equations included.  You'll need to decide if its going to be adiabatic (a great big hole) or constant temperature (little tiny hole).

Comment: Roger Wood, thank you so much! This is super!

Comment: But this doesn't take into account the fact that the pressure in the aircraft is decreasing (because the air is escaping).